# initialize a C string with multiple quoted strings

Tags: c, string

I thought a C string can be initialized with one and only one quoted string. I just wonder how is this correct?

```
char const help_message [] =   
   "Usage: %s [options] files ...\n"   
   "\n"   
   "Options include:\n"   
   " --verbose -v    Be verbose\n"   
   " --help -h       Print this help message\n"   
   " --output -o     Specify output file\n"     
   "\n" ;   

 printf (help_message, argv [0]) ;
```

Comment: I guess you thought wrong :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjacent string literals are concatenated, and this is useful two ways: **macros** which combine strings and **visualizing multi-line string literals** such as you have above.  Compare how that code would look otherwise:

```
char const help_message[] = "Usage: %s [options] files ...\n\nOptions include:\n --verbose -v    Be verbose\n --help -h       Print this help message\n --output -o     Specify output file\n\n";
```

Imagine trying to maintain that instead.  In addition, if you use a multi-line string literal, you have to either escape newlines or deal with whatever the source code uses, which may not be `'\n'`, and you'll have to watch your indentation carefully.  All of which makes the code in your example better.

Here's an example of the macro case:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(v) #v
#define STRINGIZE(v) STRINGIZE_(v)

#define LOCATION __FILE__ ":" STRINGIZE(__LINE__)

#define MY_ASSERT(expr) do { \
   if (!(expr)) \
     some_function(LOCATION ": assertion failed in " \
                   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ": " #expr); \
} while (0)
```

(There are alternatives to this, such as passing separate parameters, and using the GCC-specific `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` like this is [deprecated](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_78.html) too, but the rest is handy and this is a decent "real" example, IMHO.)

Other issues brought up in that code to be aware of:

- the single `#` is the preprocessor stringize operator (`##` is the other special preprocessor operator, for token pasting)
- without the second stringize macro, you'll get `"filename.c:__LINE__"`
- using do-while doesn't break if-else and requires the macro to be used as a statement rather than an expression

  - preventing use as an expression isn't always helpful, but it is what you want for assert-like macros

Breaking if-else example:

```
if (cond) MY_ASSERT(blah);
else other();
```

Expands to:

```
if (cond) do { ... } while(0);
else other();
```

Instead of:

```
if (cond) if (...) ...;
else other();
```

Which is the incorrect and surprising:

```
if (cond) {
  if (...) {
    ...;
  }
  else {
    other();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation) will automatically concatenate adjacent strings.

This can be quite useful to increase readability, as in your example, or with some preprocessor functions:

```
#define LOG(x) printf("%s", "Logging: " x)

LOG("HeyHey");
```

Pretty contrived example, but gets the point across.

Comment: Not if the string might contain a `%` character.  `puts("Logging: " x)` is a possibility, though.

Comment: @Johannes: Like caf said, the first argument for `printf` is a string to be formatted, and I was going to avoid that (plus it's a natural reaction to protect against buffer-attacks). In reality, this function might actually benefit more from just placing `x` in with `"Logging: "`, to allow for formatting.

Comment: `printf("Logging: %s", x)` makes more sense and doesn't require x to be a string literal.  And don't forget puts adds a newline which wasn't in the example (fputs doesn't).

Comment: @caf: What would be the problem with string containing a `%` character in this case???

Comment: AndreyT: `printf("something with %s")` (notice no more parameters) is an error.  It will result in either a compile-time problem (GCC's -Wformat) or undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, but GMan's code looks differently. He's doing `printf("%s", "something with %s")`. I don't see any problems in this case.

Comment: AndreyT: My comment (and GMan's first comment) were both responses to a now-deleted comment that suggested just `printf("Logging: " x)`.  Beware the retconning!

Answer (score 2):

Because adjacent quoted strings are considered to be part of the same string by the compiler.  The grammar of C specifically allows this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be confused with an array of strings:

```
{"xxx" ,
"yyyy",
"3534"}
```

What you posted is a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Your initializer contains only one string literal. What looks like multiple ""-enclosed string literals will actually be merged into a single string literal at the 6-th stage of translation (after preprocessing).